# Google Streetview don't hide marker at large distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I am using the Google Maps API v3 (Streetview) to "preview" the looks of a wind turbine at a location. I am currently using a marker with a custom image to show the wind turbine on the map. This works all as expected, the windmills show up and look quite nice. However, when I am further away, at some point the markers no longer display. (see link)

[One of the turbines no longer displays.. :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mEFV.jpg)

Does anyone know if it is possible to make markers visible over a longer distance?

I adapted the StreetView marker example from Google maps.

EDIT:
What I am basically trying to achieve is making the markers show up over a longer distance. What happens now is when you are far enough away from the marker, it is no longer rendered.

```js
var panorama;

function initMap() {
  
  // positions of the windmills
  var mill_pos = [
    {lat: 53.281593, lng: 6.371393},
    {lat: 53.281927, lng: 6.371424},
    {lat: 53.282388, lng: 6.371357},
    {lat: 53.282926, lng: 6.371250},
  ];

  // start position
  var startPos = {lat: 53.281413, lng: 6.371178};

  // Set up the map
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: startPos,
    zoom: 18,
    streetViewControl: false
  });

  // place the markers
  var mill_markers = [];
  mill_pos.forEach(function(pos){
    mill_markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pos,
      map: map,
      icon: 'https://www.immediateentourage.com/ie/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Wind+Turbine+Original+Photo+by+Eclipse.sx_2.png',
      title: 'Turbine'
    }))


  });

  // We get the map's default panorama and set up some defaults.
  // Note that we don't yet set it visible.
  panorama = map.getStreetView();
  panorama.setPosition(startPos);
  panorama.setPov(/** @type {google.maps.StreetViewPov} */({
    heading: 0,
    pitch: 0
  }));
  panorama.setVisible(true);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#floating-panel {
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="map"></div>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBYkokiNLc6ksDgKlkI0aLuhF9Lwbl1dX0&callback=initMap"></script>

</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4f9bwxfc/

It would be great if anyone knew how to fix this!

Comment: if you go back on the road  you can see  that  all the markrs disapperas .. a long distance not only one

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I will edit my question. I think there might be an option somewhere to specify the maximum distance at which markers are visible, however I couldn't find it so far.